# Python: evaluating variables in lists when called, not pointing to the object

Tags: python

I think I am just going down the wrong path with my code. I was hoping to get some pythonic answers.

I would like to be able to generate a list of [object.name, object]. A method would then be used to search the list for the object.name and then return the object. The user should also be able to change object.name   The code below sets up the classes.

```
class a():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class b():
    def __init__(self):
        self.graph = []
    def make_a(self, name):
        new_a = a(name)
        self.graph.append([new_a.name, new_a])
```

A user would then enter:

```
obj_B = b()
obj_B.make_a('jack')
obj_B.graph
[['jack', <a instance at 0x02FB2260>]]
```

The user should then be able to do:

```
obj_B.graph[0][1].name = 'jill'
```

Then the output of `obj_B.graph` should then be:

```
[['jill', <a instance at 0x02FB2260>]]
```

While writing this I realized I should probably just use a dictionary and then write a method to create new and delete old dictionary keys. If anyone has any better ideas I'd be thankful to see them.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should definitely use a dictionary (there's not too much more to say)

Comment: Pretty similar to `obj.__dict__` in spirit...

Comment: Whatever approach you use, encapsulate it in class b.  Don't make the user have to know how it is organized.  Provide a rename() method or something similar.  You can then easily change your implementation as needed.

Answer (score 0):

As @David Robinson pointed out, it sounds like you're trying to reimplement `dict`'s functionality. However, to address the original question, the problem you're having is that strings are immutable. When you write `obj_B.graph[0][1].name = 'jill'`, you are changing the reference held in the instance of `a`'s `name`, but not the reference in `obj_B.graph`. Consider the following:

```
>>> a = 'hello'
>>> b = a  # b is now a reference to the same str object as a
>>> id(a)
4305179104
>>> id(b)
4305179104
>>> b is a
True
>>> a = 'goodbye'  # create a new str object in the heap, and change the reference belonging to a
>>> id(a)
4305179152  # not the same object as before!
>>> id(b)
4305179104  # b is the same
>>> b is a
False
```

Compare this to mutable types, which are modified in-place:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = a
>>> a.append(4)  # we are not reassigning a, just modifying the list object it points to
>>> print a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> print b
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b is a
True
```

This applies whether the references are variables in a namespace or entries in a list.

The solution to your original question is to make `name` a method and access it with a call, like this:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name
    def set_name(self, name):
        self._name = name
    def get_name(self):
        return self._name

>>> l = []
>>> a = A('jack')
>>> l.append((a.get_name, a))
>>> l[0][1].set_name('jill')
>>> l[0][0]()
'jill'
```

Alternatively, you could give the class a `__str__` method and use that to return the name. That way you only need single entries in the list:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

>>> l = []
>>> l.append(A('jack'))
>>> str(l[0])
'jack'
>>> l[0].name = 'jill'
>>> str(l[0])
'jill'
```

PS, if you're using Python 2.x, *all* the classes you write should inherit from `object`. That is, your classdefs should read `class a(object):` etc. This is necessary for your classes to be *new-style*, which is [highly desirable](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes). The old-style classes (which do not inherit from `object`) are simply there for backwards-compatibility. In Python 3 this is no longer necessary, as all classes are new-style.